# Not able to delete multiple files along with other data in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to delete all data related to a posting when it is deleted. I have them in different tables. I am able to delete everything except images.

PS.. I am talking about image file deletion from upload folder. I can delete the rows from table already.

Model:

```
function delete_listing_id($id){
    $this->db->delete('vbc_vacation_item_attri', array('vbc_item_id' => $id));
    $this->db->delete('vbc_property_amenities', array('v_ref_id' => $id));
    $this->db->delete('vbc_property_images', array('property_ref_id' => $id));
    //unlink($url1);
    //return TRUE;
}
```

Controller:

```
function delete_listing_id() {
    if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
    $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $this->my_listings_model->delete_listing_id($id);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('listing_deleted', 'Listing successfully deleted.');
    $this->my_listings();
    }
```

And I have used this method when I uploaded them:

```
    //some Code
    $config['file_name']      = 'property_image_1';
    // Some Code
    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . 'uploads/';
    // Some Code
    $data['images'] = implode(',',$image_name);
```

Someone please help..

Comment: No, because right now there is no code to execute image deletion.. But rest of data from other 3 tables get deleted smoothly..

Comment: I am sorry.. I didn't mention that it's for deleting files from upload folder.. UPDATING THE QUESTION NOW..

Comment: Please edit your post, so we won't have any confusion.

Comment: You could use the path of the images from the database and use it in your  `unlink($url)`

Comment: Yes, I have done it for one image deletion.. but here I have to deal with array of images url I guess and how to separate them, that is the answer I am after..

Comment: You could use foreach to loop the unlink

Comment: okay.. I will give it a go.. Thanks.